# How to set " invocationCount = variable" in TestNG

Tags: variables, dynamic, testng

I want to do different performance data in one suite.
such as

```
@Test(invocationCount = 100)
@Test(invocationCount = 200)
@Test( invocationCount = 500)
@Test( invocationCount = 1000)
```

but I found there is no solution to set the variable to invocationCount.
And need to copy a lot of code to make the invocationCount different.

Could you help me on how to set the variable to invocationCount ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to set the invocationCount at runtime, then I believe your only option is TestNG Listeners.  You can modify the annotations right before a test method runs.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners